# Counting dashes within 2 separate strings, returning true if there are the same amount of dashes in the same positions of each string?

Tags: java, string, boolean

I have to write a program in Java that compares two strings for dashes. The test only returns true if each string has the same amount of dashes in the same position in the strings.

Example:

Comparing the following two strings

String string1 = "two-twenty-nine"
String string2 = "ten-fourty-five and I'm hungry."

with the above criteria would return true. It doesn't matter whether one string is longer than the other.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

I have tried:
- converting the strings to char arrays and then comparing the indexes
- Using String.indexOf() for each string, and then creating a variable int newStart = String.indexOf() with the index of the previous dash as the new starting point to look from

```
`   public static void sameDashes(String string1, String string2) {
    int count = 0;
    char index1 = ' ';
    char index2 = ' ';
    char dash = '-';
    char[] string1Array = string1.toCharArray();
    char[] string2Array = string2.toCharArray();
    while (count < string1Array.length && count < string2Array.length) {
        if (string1Array[index1] == dash && string2Array[index2] == dash) {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems home work .Post what you have done so far.

Comment: What have you tried?  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for posting guidelines.  Questions of the form "please write code for me" are generally considered not constructive on SO.

Comment: Seems like getting the position of the dashes in, say, an array or collection, for each string and comparing them would work--what have you tried so far?

Comment: Good to read what have you tried! The first way you've tried looks promising, it would help if you post that code and ask exactly where you have problems. As you can see, there are other solutions to this problem (there are 2 answers by now). Keep the effort!

Comment: @JimGarrison, I don't want anyone to write code for me, I just don't want to use arrays if I don't have to, especially if I can accomplish using String methods.

Comment: Is the answer true or false if neither string has a dash?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, my prof didn't specify.

Comment: I don't know if my loop and if-statement is set up correctly

Comment: I think the condition you want in your loop above is actually `if ((string1Array[index1] == dash) == (string2Array[index2] == dash))`. Notice that I switched `&&` for `==`. This is because you want either both *or neither* to be a dash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I suspect this is homework, I'm just going to outline a solution.

- Iterate through *string1* using the `indexOf` method, and get a `List` of `Integer`s representing the positions of the dashes.
- Iterate through *string2* in the same manner.  (You could call a general method twice.  Once with *string1* and once with *string2*.)
- Compare your `List`s, and see if they have the same `size()`.
- If they're the same size, loop through both lists and see if the positions are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Super simple using [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

1. Pad both strings with a single character on each end (i.e. `str = " " + str + " "`).
2. Call `.split("-")` on both strings and store the resulting arrays.
3. If the arrays are different lengths then the strings don't match.
4. Otherwise, compare the lengths of the corresponding strings in each array, and if the lengths of any pair don't match then the strings don't match. Except if it was the last pair of strings—then they can be different lengths and they still match (i.e. just ignore the last pair of strings—you don't need to compare the strings at the last index in the arrays).
5. Otherwise, the two strings match.

Answer (score 0):

A simple algorithm to solve this problem would be by using `indexOf()` and `charAt()` and looping through one of the string's instances of `-`.

1. Start the index-offset at `0`.
2. Get the next position of a `-` in `string1` from the given offset.
3. Check if `string2` contains characters at the position found, if so, check if it's a `-`. If it's not a `-`, the check has failed.
4. Set the index-offset to the next `-` in `string1` and repeat #2.
5. After all `-`'s have been found in `string1`, check if `string2` contains a `-` at a point further in the string than `string1` contained. If it does, the check has failed. If it doesn't, the check has passed!

Sample proof-of-concept:

```
int index = string1.indexOf("-", 0);
while (index > 0) {
    // if string2 doesn't contain a dash at the current position, return false
    if ((string2.length() <= index) || (string2.charAt(index) != "-")) return false;
    index = string1.indexOf("-", (index + 1));
}
// do one last final check to see if string2 contains a dash that's further than string1's last dash
return !(string2.indexOf("-", string1.lastIndexOf("-") + 1) > 0);
```

Comment: I think you missed the part about "same position."

Comment: Also since it is probably homework don't post raw code but rather help OP to solve this on her own.

Comment: This fails if string2 is shorter than string1.

Comment: @SarelBotha Thanks for noticing! Updated to fix

Comment: @newfurniturey it looks like OP wants to learn or else she hadn't edited the question marking her tries. Also, when you provide an answer, try to keep cool and remember number 7 of [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/182862)

Answer (score 0):

I'll place an algorithm for this problem:

- Check which `String` is the shortest: s1 or s2. Let's call the shortes string ss.
- With ss, use [`String#indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,int%29) to get the next position of the dash (or w/e char you need).
- With the position, check in that position of the other `String` if it has a dash (or the character you're looking for). You can use [`String#charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) method for this purpose.
- If the characters match, keep the loop until you get the index -1 (this means the character isn't in ss anymore).
- Check if the other string contains the character from the last valid index. If there are no more, then both Strings have the same amount of dashes. no otherwise.

In this solution, there is no need to use an additional array to check the positions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package samedashes;
```

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SameDashes {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      sameDash();
}

public static void sameDash() {
    String s1;
    String s2;
    char dash = '-';
    float cnt = 0;
    float s1dash = 0;
    float s2dash = 0;
    float totaldash1 = 0;
    int minlength=0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a string->");
    s1 = in.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter a string->");
    s2 = in.nextLine();

    if(s1.length()<s2.length()){
        minlength=s1.length();
    }else{
        minlength=s2.length();
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        if (s1.charAt(i) == dash) {
            s1dash++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
        if (s2.charAt(i) == dash) {
            s2dash++;
        }
    }


    System.out.println("String1 dashes->" + s1dash);
    System.out.println("String2 dashes->" + s2dash);

    totaldash1 = s1dash + s2dash;


    if (totaldash1 % 2 == 0 && s1.contains("-") && s2.contains("-")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < minlength; i++) {
            if (s1.charAt(i) == dash && s2.charAt(i) == dash) {
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        if (cnt >=1) {
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding a little explanation to your code: why and how does it work for example...